# Saving data from a 2d array into file through a function in neural network

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, 2d, neural-network

I am newBie to neural networks. I have 2 functions. Initializing weights and saving weights. When i am initializing weights i also need to save them in a  separate file.

I have the following code:

```
//Function for saving weights
void saveWeights(int Hidden, int Inputs, double arr[][?]){
  //double arr[][?];
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("weights.txt");
     for(int j = 0;j<Hidden;j++){
        for(int i = 0;i<Inputs;i++){
            myfile<<arr[i][j]<<endl;
        }
     }
    myfile.close();
}

// set weights to random numbers
void initWeights(void){
     for(int j = 0;j<numHidden;j++){
        weightsHO[j] = getRand(0,1);
        for(int i = 0;i<numInputs;i++){
         weightsIH[i][j] = getRand(0,1);
         cout<<"Weights = "<<weightsIH[i][j]<<endl;
         saveWeights(numHidden, numInputs, weightsIH[i][j]);             
        }
      }
}
```

The problem is i don't know what value to pass for the column in a 2D array, as it is a variable length array.

Can you plz guide what to do further?

I have also tried the following:

```
    //Function for saving weights
void saveWeights(double w){
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("weights.txt");
            myfile<<w<<endl;
    myfile.close();
}

// set weights to random numbers
void initWeights(void){
     for(int j = 0;j<numHidden;j++){
        weightsHO[j] = getRand(0,1);
        for(int i = 0;i<numInputs;i++){
         weightsIH[i][j] = getRand(0,1);
         z = weightsIH[i][j];
         //cout<<"Weights = "<<weightsIH[i][j]<<endl;
         saveWeights(z);             
        }
      }
}
```

A generic code showing how to perform this operation would be helpful.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `std::vector` rather than naked C-style arrays. A lot more robust and convenient and you can use `.size()` to get the dimension.

Comment: If there is a *tight constraint*, I'm positive there shouldn't, then make it a template that has two std::size_t template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of possible solutions.

1) write dimension of you array as the first number (set of numbers) in the file.

2) insert NEW_LINE_CARACTER ('\n', i.e. endl) after each line when writing to file and separate numbers by space.

```cpp
     for(int j = 0;j<Hidden;j++){
        for(int i = 0;i<Inputs;i++){
            myfile<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        myfile<<endl
     }
```

3) make additional file with settings like dimensions.

4) use data structures different from C-style arrays and try serialization.

etc.